# text file doesn't match when i try to create text box according to the text file

Tags: c#, textbox, split, text-files, panel

my text file looks like this ( 10 by 10 ) :

[image]

So what i am trying to do , i want to display 100 text boxes , i use string split by comma to detect how many text boxes to create and it suppose to be 100 . but when i tried to do it , it display 110 textboxes , 10 more textboxes than usual . What gone wrong here?

Heres my code :

```
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath(@daoWordPuzzle.GetfileURL())))
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //  Response.Write(line + " <br />"); // Read every line in text file.
                string[] lol = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                foreach (var value in lol)
                {
                    int i = 0;

                    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                    tb.MaxLength = (1);
                    tb.Width = Unit.Pixel(40);
                    tb.Height = Unit.Pixel(40);
                    tb.ID = i.ToString();

                    // Response.Write(value);
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    {
                        tb.Text = "";
                     //   tb.Style["visibility"] = "hidden";
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    {
                        tb.Text = "";
                    }


                       Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);

                    i++;
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's creating 10 more because you have 10 lines that ends with a comma. Say you have a string like:

```
var s = "A,B,C,"
```

Splitting this would result in 4 string, the last one being empty. Now reproduce this for 10 lines and you will get the same behaviour as you are having. If that's unwanted behaviour, you need to change your logic to take into account a line that is ending with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to miss the first line or your text file, your code should be:

```
string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
[...]
}
```

Also if you want 10 boxes per row your text file should have 9 commas per row, but yours has 10.